add bounce to an object
I am trying to simulate a ball in gazebo. I am able to spawn the ball in gazebo but it fells like it is very stiff. I tried using the kp tag to reduce stiffness but the ball falls through the ground when using it. I also reduced the mass of the ball to 0.0001.
Here is the URDF:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro"  name="ball_1">
    
    <!-- Variables -->
    <xacro:property name="ball_radius" value="0.05"/>
    <xacro:property name="ball_mass" value="0.001"/>

    
    <!-- MATERIALS -->    
    <material name="orange">
      <color rgba="${255/255} ${108/255} ${10/255} 1.0"/>
    </material>
    
    <!-- BASE LINK -->    
    <link name="base_link"/>        
    
    <joint name="joint_1" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="link_1"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>        
        <!--<axis xyz="0 0 0"/> -->
    </joint>    

    <!-- Ball -->
    <link name="link_1">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <sphere radius="${ball_radius}"/>    
            </geometry>            
            <material name="orange"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <sphere radius="${ball_radius}"/>    
            </geometry>                                    
        </collision>
        
        
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>            
            <mass value="${ball_mass}" />
        <inertia ixx="${(2/5) * ball_mass * (ball_radius*ball_radius)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
                    iyy="${(2/5) * ball_mass * (ball_radius*ball_radius)}" iyz="0.0"
                izz="${(2/5) * ball_mass * (ball_radius*ball_radius)}" />
        </inertial>
        
    </link>   
    
    <gazebo reference="link_1">
        <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
        <kp value="0.5"/>       <!-- the ball falls through the ground -->  
    </gazebo>
    
</robot>

I would like to know the correct usage of kp(stiffness) and kd (damping) tag in ros2 with some  example code.

You can try the solution mentioned in this answer https://answers.ros.org/question/51956/simple-question-on-setting-bounce-properties-urdf/

@Sriram Thanks it is working but the ball is having inconsistent bouncing effects. Means the ball is bouncing different number of times when released from the same height for multiple times. You can get more details here: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/111859/inconsistent-bounce-behaviour-of-ball-in-gazebo
