inconsistent bounce behaviour of ball in gazebo
I am trying to simulate a tennis ball in gazebo. The issue is that the ball is having inconsistent bouncing effects. Means the ball is bouncing different number of times when released from the same height for multiple times.

1st Drop: 4 bounce
2nd Drop: 2 bounce
3rd drop: ball stuck in ground without any bounce.

I need to have consistent bouncing effect because I need to predict the ball trajectory when applied force in x direction while the ball is in the air.
I have gone through the following post but changing iteration dose not seems to help.
URDF
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro"  name="ball_1"> 
    <!-- Variables -->
    <xacro:property name="ball_radius" value="0.05"/>
    <xacro:property name="ball_mass" value="0.001"/>

    
    <!-- MATERIALS -->    
    <material name="orange">
      <color rgba="${255.0/255.0} ${108.0/255.0} ${10.0/255.0} 1.0"/>
    </material>
    
    <!-- BASE LINK -->    
    <link name="base_link"/>        
    
    <joint name="joint_1" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="link_1"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>        
    </joint>    

    <!-- Ball -->
    <link name="link_1">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <sphere radius="${ball_radius}"/>    
            </geometry>            
            <material name="orange"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <sphere radius="${ball_radius}"/>    
            </geometry>                                    
        </collision>
        
        
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>            
            <mass value="${ball_mass}" />
        <inertia ixx="${(2/5) * ball_mass * (ball_radius*ball_radius)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
                    iyy="${(2/5) * ball_mass * (ball_radius*ball_radius)}" iyz="0.0"
                izz="${(2/5) * ball_mass * (ball_radius*ball_radius)}" />
        </inertial>    
            
    </link>   
    
    <gazebo reference="link_1">
        <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
        
        <maxVel value="20.0"/>       

        <kp value="100000000.0" />
        <kd value="1.0" />
            
    </gazebo>
    
</robot>

Launch File
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node

from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

import xacro


def generate_launch_description():
    
    
    # Process the URDF file
    pkg_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ball_spawner'))
    xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path,'description','copy_ball.urdf.xacro')
    robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file)
    
    # ROBOT STATE PUBLISHER    
    # Create a robot_state_publisher node
    params = {'robot_description': robot_description_config.toxml()}
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[params]
    )


    # RVIZ
    rviz = Node(
            package='rviz2',
            executable='rviz2',
            output='screen'
        )
    
    # Include the Gazebo launch file, provided by the gazebo_ros package
    gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')]),
                    launch_arguments={'world': "./src/ball_spawner/worlds/world_1.world"}.items()
             )

    # Run the spawner node from the gazebo_ros package. The entity name doesn't really matter if you only have a single robot.
    spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                        arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                                   '-entity', 'ball_bot'],
                        output='screen')
    

    # Launch!
    return LaunchDescription([
        node_robot_state_publisher,
        rviz,
        gazebo,
        spawn_entity,
    ])


The issue was with the .world file. Decrease max_step_size and increase real_time_update_rate. After changing the values of the following tags, the issue is resolved:
      <max_step_size>0.0001</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
      <real_time_update_rate>10000</real_time_update_rate>

Here I have just decreased max_step_size by adding one zero 0.001 -> 0.0001 and increased real_time_update_rate by adding one zero 1000 -> 10000.
There are combination of some other values that works as well but this one is easy to tune.
What I have observed is this issue does not have a specific solution. For similar issue I mentioned in the question, the solution was to change iteration of solver form 50 to 100, in my case changing some other values helped. You need to try different combination of values under  tag in a world file.
NOTE: Having correct value of inertial tag for a link when specifying the URDF is very important for consistent behavior of an object.
Thanks
